# JQuery Modal window with OK button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a modal window with a OK button that executes this code:

```
window.onload = callFunction2(p_num);
```

This is the function that opens the modal window

```
function showCloseDialog () {
  var l_title       = 'title';
  var l_detail_text = 'some text';

  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                        .html(l_detail_text)
                        .dialog({ autoOpen : false
                        , title    : l_title
                        , modal    : true
                        , width    : 'auto'
                        , buttons  : [ { text  : "OK"
                                       , click : function() {
                                           $dialog.dialog('close');
                                          }
                                        }
                                      ]
                        } );
  $dialog.dialog('open');                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement the way it is specified in following link

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

They have provided example and source code to show how it is implemented.

Comment: greate do you know how to remove that horizontal black line from modal? that divides text from buttons?

Comment: use thie css class to override the default css and remove black line .ui-widget-content{border:none;}

Comment: open          : function(event, ui) {
                          $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                          $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
                          $(".ui-widget-content-border").hide(); ???
                           }

Comment: You can use this - $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane')[0].style.border = "none";

Comment: greate you help me a lot

Comment: can you share the documentation where you get all of this stuff, please?